# setup deployment: How to give permissions to the C: directory application folder database?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, permissions, setup-deployment

I have done a little app in C# .Net and it uses a Access database. The app is finished but I have a little problem when I try to install it by install Shield. 
I did some research and the problem seems to be permissions. The database is short and is in the app folder (C:Programs/app Folder).
In my PCs, I install and run it successfuly because I am the administrator of the system, but when I install it in other PCs the app can read data fom database but it can´t insert data.

My question is: How I can give permissions to write on database keeping the database on the app directory?

thanks in advance

Comment: That's why Microsoft has been advising developers to store files that need to be written in user specific or common files folders for years...

Comment: so the best solution is to put the access file in another directory like Documents ? In that whay, it is necessary to configure the conection string after install the application in every machines ... That is not what I want.

Comment: You could generate the connection string dynamically in code.

Comment: that could be the best. And how can I do that ? lets assume I put the database in C:\user\Documents . In each machine the "user" is diferent. So, how I make the setup deployment save the database file in documents, and grab the right path to the database ?

Comment: You try to put it in the program's installation folder, which means that you want all users of the machine to access the same database. This also means you could put the database into the common application data folder (`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)`), which is "The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data that is used by all users." (from MSDN). All you need to do is put the database there in your setup and construct the connection string in code using the appropriate connection string builder.

Comment: I read some threads where someone tells that isn´t possible write on that folder if you havent UAC permission (for example, regular user). It´s that true ?
I think I will read the conection string from app.config and change taht file after each installation...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `cacls` or `xcacls` tool to grant write to the mdb file and create file on the directory.

Comment: But that tool I need to run it after install the application right ? The problem is I am not who is gone install the app in other machines and they dont know how to do it. I want something like change C# code to give permissions or make a install setup that give the permissions. Is that possible ?